# Run Python scripts on Jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins, import

I am trying to run my python automation on Jenkins. The scripts can be started on local PC. I already pip install 'request'. But when I try to start the scripts on Jenkins, it shows:

```
Building in workspace C:\Users\Desktop\Automation\CGN_automation
[CGN_automation] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins401971882258893188.bat

C:\Users\Desktop\Automation\CGN_automation>python testCase_100_856451.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testCase_100_856451.py", line 9, in <module>
    from cgnTestLib import *
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\Automation\CGN_automation\cgnTestLib.py", line 2, 
in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

C:\Users\Desktop\Automation\CGN_automation>exit 1 
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: probably not the same user/machine. Install requests on the machine that runs jenkins slaves, as admin or as the user which actually runs the jobs. Or put the "requests" module at the same level as your script...

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct python version? Sometimes multiple python's are installed on one machine. The issue is clear: You have to install the module